# Same Generic commit object getting saved from different instances

Tags: javers

I am using Javers version 5.1.2, with jdk 11, in my application, where I am committing Generic Object T and saving into mongodb. The Generic commit objects are actually created from generic rest service, where user can pass any Json.
Every thing is going fine on single instance. Whenever any re commit is sent with same request, Javers commit.getChanges().isEmpty() method returns true.

Issues:
1) Whenever same request to sent to different instance, commit.getChanges().isEmpty() method returns false.
2) If I commit one request, and restart the instance and then again commit, commit.getChanges().isEmpty() again returns false. Instead of true.

As a result of above issue, new version is getting created if request goes to different new instance or instance is restarted.

Could you please let me know, how we can handle this issue.

I will extract code from the project and will create a sample running project and share.
Right now, I can share few classes, please see, if these help:

---

//---------------------Entitiy Class:

```
import java.util.Map;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class ClientEntity<T> {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String entityId;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private T commitObj;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String authorName;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private boolean major;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Map<String, String> commitProperties;


}
```

//--------DataIntegrator

```
@Service
public class DataIntegrator {

    private final Javers javers;

    private IVersionRepository versionDao;

    private IdGenerator idGenerator;

    @Inject
    public DataIntegrator(Javers javers, IVersionRepository versionDao, IdGenerator idGenerator) {
        this.javers = javers;
        this.versionDao = versionDao;
        this.idGenerator = idGenerator;
    }

    public <T> String commit(ClientEntity<T> clientObject) {
        CommitEntity commitEntity = new CommitEntity();
        commitEntity.setEntityId(clientObject.getEntityId());
        commitEntity.setEntityObject(clientObject.getCommitObj());

        Map<String, String> commitProperties = new HashMap<>();
        commitProperties.putAll(clientObject.getCommitProperties());
        commitProperties.put(commit_id_property_key, clientObject.getEntityId());
        commitProperties.putAll(idGenerator.getEntityVersions(clientObject.getEntityId(), clientObject.isMajor()));

        Commit commit = javers.commit(clientObject.getAuthorName(), commitEntity, commitProperties);

        if (commit.getChanges().isEmpty()) {
            return "No Changes Found";
        }
        versionDao.save(
                new VersionHead(clientObject.getEntityId(), Long.parseLong(commitProperties.get(major_version_id_key)),
                        Long.parseLong(commitProperties.get(minor_version_id_key))));

        return commit.getProperties().get(major_version_id_key) + ":"
                + commit.getProperties().get(minor_version_id_key);
    }
}
```

---

1) `commitObj` is a Generic object, in ClientEntity, which holds Json coming from the Rest webService. The JSON can be any valid json. Can have nested structure also.
2) After calling `javers.commit` method, we are checking if it is existing entity or there is any change using `commit.getChanges().isEmpty()`.

- If same second request goes to same instance, it returns true for change, as expected
- If same second request goes to different instance, under load balancer, it takes it as different request and `commit.getChanges().isEmpty()` returns false. Expected response should be true, as it is same version.
- If after first request, I restart instance, and make a same request, it returns false, instead of true, which means, `getChanges` method taking the same request as same.

Comment: Do you have a working code sample that reproduces the issue you are describing here? This will help the community answer your question better.

Comment: Hi Christine, I have added few useful classes. Please see if these can help.